# Calling JavaScript On Click Before Landing Page URL Evaluates?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to call a JavaScript file on click. Once the file loads, I want to redirect the user to a landing page.

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    document.getElementsByTagName("body").onclick = function () {
        var js = document.createElement("script");
        js.type = "text/javascript";
        js.onload = function () {
            window.location.href = "https://google.com/";
        };
        js.src = "((JAVASCRIPT SOURCE))";
        document.body.appendChild(js);
     };
    </script>
```

The purpose of delaying the landing page until the script loads is because some browsers load the landing page before the script does and I need the script to be called for tracking purposes. It's just used to capture total "clicks", if you will.

Can you help me figure out why the above is not working? I try to invoke the script when the body is clicked on, and then once the script loads, use window.open to go to the landing page.

Thanks,

Comment: also, please dont suggest using any jquery if possible. thanks!

Comment: One thing to note is that `window.open` is a native function (which seems to open a pop-up rather than redirect) and you are overwriting it which will have no behavior aside from erasing the original native function. Maybe you meant `window.location.href`. Setting that property typically causes the browser to redirect.

Comment: Just to be sure, I would set `js.onload` before setting `js.src` and before calling `appendChild`. I am not sure when the browser will start downloading the script, but if it finishes before you configure `js.onload`, `js.onload` will have no effect.

Comment: Thanks! I made both of these changes but still no luck. Any other ideas?

Comment: I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all `document.getElementsByTagName()` returns a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection):

> The Element.getElementsByTagName() method returns a live HTMLCollection of elements with the given tag name.

To access the first element, to be able to attach your event listener, you have to do this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].onclick = function () { ... }
```

And instead of `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]` you could just use this shorthand, which you already used further down:

```
document.body.onclick = function () { ... }
```

Also, if your script is placed in `<head>` you need to wrap it in `onLoad` or `onDOMContentLoaded`:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.body.onclick = function() {
    var js = document.createElement("script");
    js.type = "text/javascript";
    js.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js";
    document.body.appendChild(js);
    js.onload = function() {
      window.location.href = "https://www.example.com";
    };
  };
}
```

```html
CLICK ME
```